# NTP doesnt sync my time

Tags: linux, troubleshooting, ntp, suse

Im getting problems to sync my local time with the NTP Server.

this is the output when u do a NTP Query.

```
 remote           refid           st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 timeserver.      .INIT.          16 u  780 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

i got `.INIT.` in the refid why??

when i try to sync the local time using this command:

```
service ntp ntptimeset
```

it given me this output:

```
Time could not be synchronized
```

looking if server is running ok with:

```
service ntp status

 remote           refid           st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 timeserver.      .INIT.          16 u  780 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000

Checking for network time protocol daemon (NTPD):                       running
```

i've tried with this command to force the NTP Server.

```
sntp -P no -r timeserver.
```

but i got this output.

```
sntp: KoD package 'INIT' received.
sntp: KoD package 'INIT' received.
sntp: KoD package 'INIT' received.
sntp: KoD package 'INIT' received.
sntp: KoD package 'INIT' received.
sntp: KoD package 'INIT' received.
sntp: too many bad or lost packets
```

any idea how could handle this error?, if you need more information just tellme, i did `traceroute` to the Time Server an is reacheable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refid .INIT. and stratum 16 indicates that you are not getting any responses from those servers. Check your firewall(s).

Comment: ill do, this will take some time (burocracy) lets see...

Comment: after some fight with security, it solved, something they did mby some rules. ty was Fw issue.